# Is it possible to factor a complex number?

Tags: complex-analysis, factoring

Say i have a complex number $5+5i$, is it then possible to factor out a five, so that:

$5+5i$ becomes $5(1+i)$

Arithmetically this would work, but I don't know if I mix thr real and imaginary part or something when I do so. So is this possible?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. This is called the [distributive property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributive_property) which can be done in any [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)).

Comment: Yes, thank you. This is the answer i was looking for. Of course it will work arithmetically, but i didn't know if was legal.

Answer (score 1):

This would definitely work. By distributivity:
$$
5(1+i)=5\cdot 1+5\cdot i=5+5i
$$